# Determine self.view size in loadView of UIViewController

Tags: ios, ios4, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom `UIViewController` subclass and I want to override the `loadView` method. I bumped into the problem that I need the size of the `self.view` before it is added to its parent (which is a `UIViewControllerWrapperView`). How can I get the size of the `UIViewControllerWrapperView` that my `view` is going to be added to?

If this is not the method that is commonly used, then what should I do to determine the future size of my view manually (and not rely on autosizing)?

EDIT:

Also, when is this `UIViewControllerWrapperView` created and sized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what I want is not possible with the current SDK possibilities, apart perhaps from trying to calculate the space on your screen by yourself.

I solved my problem by setting the autosizing masks of my views in a bit cleverer way.

EDIT: It turned out that I can determine the size I needed in `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` .

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you can determine the size in `-(void)viewWillAppear:`? My custom view still has no size, and has no superView to adjust to.
Edit: I already have `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` set as the autoResizingMask, but that doesn't help

Comment: @BobVork, I haven't worked with that codebase for over a year now and have forgotten what exactly happens there. I think it was related to initializing the view with a CGRectZero and then setting the autoresizing masks (that you already have). Check the relevant code here - http://pastebin.com/m8kNqJbY

Answer (score 0):

If you're overriding your view controller's -loadView method, you'll need to create the entire view hierarchy there.

Edit: I previously suggested calling `[super loadView]`, but I notice that the docs say not to do that.

Comment: @Caleb, I do not want to use a nib file. I want to know the available space when I am in loadView so that I can get its dimensions there. The problem is that I don't know how large my view will be and I need it at that point.

Comment: You can use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]` to get the size that your view should fill.

Comment: @Caleb, I don't need the application frame - I need the UIViewControllerWrapperView size. That is going to be different from the application frame, as my custom view controller is a part of a navigation controller.

Comment: I don't think the information you're looking for is available during `-loadView`, since the view controller has to load its view before the view can be added to the nav controller's view. You could create a custom view that knows how to arrange its subviews in `-layoutSubviews`, or you could arrange your views in -viewWillAppear. Or, you can just assume a certain size, like 416x320 (416 = screen height - (nav bar + status bar)), which is basically what most folks do in their nib files.

Comment: I have a custom view and am doing layouting in lyoutSubviews. However, I create my views shortly after viewDidLoad and at that point, the view property of my custom view controller doesn't have a parent and is not autosized. So, I run into problems when I try to layout my custom view.

Comment: I don't understand. `-layoutSubviews` should arrange its subviews according to the view's bounds, without worrying about parent views, etc. When the nav controller adds your view controller's view, it will set the view's frame, which causes -layoutSubviews to be called.

Comment: It doesn't! That's what surprised me the most! `layoutSubviews` gets called, after that the parent gets resized and `layoutSubviews` does not get called anymore! I don't understand this... I even tried calling layoutIfNeeded in drawRect and it doesn't get called! It only got called when I manually invoked `layoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html):

> If a view controller is not loaded from a storyboard, create a 
>   custom initialization method that is specific to your view controller. 
>   This method should call the super class’s init method and then perform 
>   any class specific initialization.

This seems to indicate that the child view controller should be passed the parent's view size information via a customized initializer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle the size of the current view (or view controller) is not to worry about it, and just use AutoLayout or (older way) auto resizing masks to lay things out naturally within this view.

At some point you can of course figure out what your own dimensions are, but you should try to redo your design so that your layout is all relative. Instead of saying "my width is 320, so this subview should have width 280 with 20 px on each side" you can use AutoLayout to effectively say "make the subview have a 20 px buffer on the left and right, and occupy whatever width remains". etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but AutoLayout was introduced more than a year after I originally posted the question and found a solution to my problem. At the time, if I had AutoLayout, my life would have been much simpler :)